# I want to get column data from sql server using datatable and store it in a string variable?

Tags: c#

```
query = "select id from user_detail where status='Processing...'";
        DataTable datatable = Handler.FetchDataTable(query);
        if (datatable != null && datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            data = (datatable).ToString();
        }
```

this is my code. i want to get all record from column and store it in data variable one by one

Comment: The code that you have already; is it working? is there a problem? a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the ideal way to do this is with ["dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
List<string> ids = connection.Query<string>(query).AsList();
```

Note that it supports full parameterization etc too.

However, with your existing code:

```
var col = datatable.Columns[0];

foreach(DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
{
    string s = (string)row[col];
    //...
}
```

Comment: string s = (string)row[col];
cannot convert to string

Comment: @JaiPundir ...? note the edit - that may help a little

Comment: @JaiPundir what do you want me to do with that comment?

Comment: string s = (string)row[col];  in this code it cannot convert row to string

Comment: @JaiPundir then: it isn't a string in the first place! You could change to `string s = Convert.ToString(row[col]);` - but personally I'd rather understand what the value actually *was*

Comment: foreach(string row in datatable.Rows) how to convert datatable.Rows in string formate

Comment: @JaiPundir look one comment above

Comment: Yes That is Fine

Comment: foreach(string row in datatable.Rows) how to convert datatable.Rows in string formate

Comment: @JaiPundir look 4 comments above; also, I'm getting a sense of deja-vu